# Issues with href not opening link (tested in Chrome and Safari)

Tags: html, href

Here's what I've got:  What I'm trying to do is have a github image on a webpage and when it is clicked it takes you to my github account.  Odd thing is that this was working and then stopped and I can't tie it directly to any changes I've made. Note that I'm not using any javascript on this site...

This is in the body of my .html:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="https://github.com/mystuff" target: "_blank">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/######/site/octocat_black.png"></a>
    <!-- this repeats for 5 different images -->
  </div>
</body>
```

When I hover over the image i can see the link in the chrome bottom toolbar but when I click it the page just seems to reload (not an entire reload, but it doesn't go anywhere).  If I use the developer tools and click on the link it goes where it's supposed to.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Note that all the images I use, .html, and .css all live in the same directory.  It's a VERY simple site.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Before adding `target="_blank"` I could not get the links to open in Chrome or Safari.  It like the page would try to do something but nothing would happen.  Once I added the `target` (and got the form correct) the links would pop-up in a new window (and therefore worked as expected).  Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
target:="_blank"
```

html is no pascal where the assignment operator is `:=`. Write:

```
target="_blank"
```

Comment: So I fixed my original post as the copy/paste from Chrome was crappy.  My target wasn't quite what you originally saw, but you're commenting clued me in on the fact that what i was doing was wrong.  Originally I had `target: "_blank"`, which clearly is wrong.  I've switched it to `target="_blank"` as you mentioned and it works.  Thanks!  Also worth noting: without the `target` the links wouldn't open.  That was my attempt at getting them to work (which failed of course due to the typo you caught)...but now they seem to work.  Thanks again!